# duplicate watermarks to show not only one times on Android 12's scrolling screenshot

Tags: android, watermark, android-app-watermark

Our requirement: would like to insert a watermark on fixed height of native android app.
When user browse the content, the watermark would not change its height. However, when user use screenshot with Android 12 and tap "Capture More", the watermarks could show many times on the scrolling screenshot(not only one watermarks on the scrolling screenshot).

Result we've tried: Our team have tried to solve it but google reject our app. Google asked that we should get users allowance to edit the picture, and then we could show several watermarks on the scrolling screenshot. But most of user would reject to allow. We worried that would be an in-effective feature.

Is there anyone having idea to deal with our requirement, please share with me!
Thousand thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could suspend the native screenshot of the device and build one on your own app, then you could decide the watermark's behavior of in-app screenshot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).